# Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted - Amazon Web Services

Tags: php, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I'm trying to set up LAMP server on amazon Linux 2 AMI instance.
I'm following the guide here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-lamp-amazon-linux-2.html

But when I try to start apache server with:

**sudo systemctl start httpd**

I get the error :
**Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted**

I'm following the complete guide on that page

Please can someone help, its my first time